# AIR / Android : Add asset and reference in manifest

Tags: android, air, android-network-security-config

I am trying to add a network_security_config.xml file to my Android / AIR application.

If it were pure Android, I would simply add it to my /res/xml/ directory and then reference it in manifest application tag with an attribute; android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

However, Adobe controls the "res" directory and uses it exclusively for compiled AS classes. Any media I add to the APK appears in the "assets" folder instead of the "res" folder and I cannot find a way to reference the XML file as a result.

Does anybody know a means for me to reference the network_security_config.xml in assets folder in my Android manifest? Or is there a better way to set network_security_config.xml for my AIR / Android APK?

Thanks,
Gaius

Comment: I have the same question.  Did you find an answer???

Comment: No, customer dumped AIR in favour of native.